# multer upload not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am trying to use the file upload feature using multer.
I'm always getting 404 error, how can I fix this?

> This is my `app.js` :

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var multer = require('multer');

app.use(multer({
  dest: './uploads/'
}).single('singleInputFileName'));
```

> This is my `router.js` :

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
   console.dir(req.files);
});
```

> And this is the form :

```
form(action='/' enctype='multipart/form-data')
 input(type='file' name='singleInputFileName')
 input(type='submit' value='Upload photo')
```

**Edit: I Have added this script to the app.js**

```js
app.post('/fileuploads', function(req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    if (err) {
      return res.end("Error uploading file.");
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.end("File is uploaded");
  });
});
```

Comment: Please review code and let me know whether it will help to you or not? I shall try to rectify it if it will not working

Comment: Something to do with express router. Somehow it seems not to work with Router. If the code is written in app.js directly then things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working snippet of multer file upload, I have tested on postman with the following code please review it and do changes accordingly.

> app.js

```
// NodeJS Core dependencies
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var createError = require('http-errors');
var session = require('express-session');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Router file in which routes implemented
var index = require("./routes/index")(app, router);
// Add routers in middleware
app.use("/", index);
// Listen application on 3000 Port
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("application running on port 3000");
});
```

> index.js

```
// NodeJS module dependencies
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${process.cwd()}/uploads/`)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase())
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
// Export routes
module.exports = function (app, router) {
    router.post('/fileupload', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) => {
        res.status(200).json({message: `File uploaded successfully on '${process.cwd()}/uploads/${req.file.filename}`});
    });
    return router;
}
```

> Package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-multer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "express-session": "1.15.6",
    "mongoose": "5.0.14",
    "moongoose": "0.0.5",
    "morgan": "1.9.0",
    "multer": "1.3.0",
    "nodemon": "1.17.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Need static folder?

Comment: @ŞükSefHam I have updated my code with upload folder path as described in the question. Thank you.

Comment: where will I put this on the 'router.js' ?

Comment: wait post an error this code is working snippet and I have used same snippet in my application it requires to resolve bug of your app.js that is main reason and when you say 404 it means the path you called is not exists in your router file

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: hold a moment my friend I working on  code you should keep patience

Comment: Hey, I edited the post and I have added some scripts in the app.js, is this correct?

Comment: I think you did not listen server can you listen your server?

Comment: @ReinardCarranceja Now I have uploaded code and this is working example I have tested in postman let me know if still is not working.

Comment: @ReinardCarranceja The code structure is identical with your application structure

Comment: I make it work, thanks. The problem is with my form action haha thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think action of form not true, try '/fileuploads'

```
form(action='/fileuploads' enctype='multipart/form-data')
input(type='file' name='singleInputFileName')
input(type='submit' value='Upload photo')
```